# Azure Dev ops replace tokens per environment in release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-release-task

i am using the Replace token extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens to replace variable in **/*.config files

Our build pipeline creates one artifact that needs to be deployed to all environments

we have 2 environments in our release pipeline(DEV ,QA)

Each environment has a set of variables configured

[image]

I have added the replace token task onto our release pipeline

[image]

My config files looks like this

[image]

The the tokens are not replaces , i Am new to Azure DevOps , am i missing anything here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Release activities run *on the release agent*. You're running token replacement **after** the application is deployed to the app service, so the token replacement isn't getting deployed.

That's one issue.

Another issue is that web deploy packages are zip archives, so token replacement isn't going to affect the files contained in the zip file. You shouldn't use token replacement in conjunction with web deploy. You should use web deploy transforms (`parameters.xml` and `SetParameters.xml`), which are supported by the web deploy task that you're using. `parameters.xml` allows you to define xpath expressions for locating elements to transform, and the `setparameters.xml` files contain the values to use in the transformation.

Comment: This works for a Windows app service but not Linux. For Linux app services, I don't even see the "File Transforms & Variable Substitution Options" section in the web deploy task. Any idea why, or how I can replace tokens for Linux? This seems very basic...