# Replace/Update json file's values during deployment on Dev, Stage and Production slots using Azure Release pipelines

Tags: json, azure-devops, continuous-deployment, azure-powershell, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am quite new in Azure and i have a task to update a json file's values at deployment time. I have 3 deployment slots in Azure release pipeline Dev, Stage and Prod.

I have following Json file which need to update.

```
"tables": [{
    "name": "CustomerContract",
    "columns": [{
               "name": "Year",
               "dataType": "int64",
               "sourceColumn": "Year",
               "summarizeBy": "none"
           },
           {
               "name": "<devname>",
               "dataType": "int64",
               "sourceColumn": "CustomerNumber",
               "summarizeBy": "none",
               "isHidden": <trueifdev>
           }
    ],
    "partitions": [{
        "name": "Partition",
        "dataView": "full"
    }]
  },
}
```

In above json file i need to update following key's values.

- "isHidden"
- "name"

above two key's values are different based on slots (Dev, Stage & Prod).

Please help me out how can i change/update the values of above keys at deployment time based on slots?

Following link didn't worked in my case because my json files belongs to sharepoint data models.

[Azure Dev ops replace tokens per environment in release pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56223728/azure-dev-ops-replace-tokens-per-environment-in-release-pipeline)

Comment: where is the `json-File` located? Is it part of your repository? You could use a custom task to solve that, depends where your `json-File` is located. I recommad powershell task for that.

Comment: json file is located in my artifact.

Comment: hm, I don't have any experiance how to access files inside the artifact.

Comment: you can use token replace task, if your json file contains tokens, if not - you can use powershell script to replace values

Comment: It is working fine. I have accepted your answer. Thank you so much. I have one more issue considering same json file. If i want to change values based on values not keys, is it possible?

Comment: @AshishJain, I didn't test it, but I think it is ok. Because this replace task is based on the syntax  `#{Variable}#`, you just need to set this in the key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Please help me out how can i change/update the values of above keys at deployment time based on slots?

If the Json file is not generated during building. We still could use the task [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) to update the key's values.

As test, change the definition of the key's values:

```
"tables": [{
    "name": "CustomerContract",
    "columns": [{
               "name": "Year",
               "dataType": "int64",
               "sourceColumn": "Year",
               "summarizeBy": "none"
           },
           {
               "name": "#{DevName}#",
               "dataType": "int64",
               "sourceColumn": "CustomerNumber",
               "summarizeBy": "none",
               "isHidden": #{trueifdev}#
           }
    ],
    "partitions": [{
        "name": "Partition",
        "dataView": "full"
    }]
  },
}
```

The format of variable in `.json` file is `#{DevName}#` & `#{trueifdev}#`.

Copy this file to the artifact and use Replace Tokens task to update the key's values:

[image]

And define the key's values on the Variables based on the stages:

[image]

As test result for stage `Stage`:

```
       {
           "name": "TDev456",
           "dataType": "int64",
           "sourceColumn": "CustomerNumber",
           "summarizeBy": "none",
           "isHidden": False
       }
```

The key's values `name` & `isHidden` have been updated to `TDev456` & `False`.

Hope this helps.